# Scrollbar in gridview

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, html, scroll

I am using a horizontal scrollbar around a gridview because not all fields fit,

Is there a way where i can set the scroll bar to appear alligned to the right rather than the standard left?

I am using:        div style="overflow :auto ;width:700px"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript.
Take a look at this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcJn8/)